# Spyder Editor does not execute code in Console

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I just installed Anaconda and trying use Spyder editor to run any (say `np.arange(10)` ) code but it does not show up in the console: I just get the following:

```
runfile('C:/Users/murad/.spyder-py3/test.py', wdir='C:/Users/murad/.spyder-py3')
```

If I type my code in console it works but if I run it from editor no output is executed!

Comment: You need to add a `print` as the last command of the code you're trying to run. Else Python won't show anything if nothing is printed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us your code?
If you just typed `np.arange(10)` in your script, then what you get in the console is normal. Try typing e.g. `print(np.arange(10))`